# Swift: CouchbaseLite.framework not worked?

Tags: swift, ipad, couchdb, xcode7, linker-errors

I am develop an swift app which I have used CouchDB database. for that I am download the couchDB framework and add into my project. It works fine on simulator but, when I am run my app on iPad device it gives one error:

'CouchbaseLite(CBLDatabase.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)'

and for that in build settings I was change the enable bitcode to Yes.
but it doesn't works for me.

Please provide some guide line or an help or comment or sample code to solved that Problem.
 Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for that error in build settings I was change the enable bitcode to No, and it works for me.